# Will there any performance impact of a Class definition structure order in C++?

Tags: c++

I have two classes as follows (C++):

```
class A {
private:
    int v1;
    char c;
    long long v2;
    double v3;
    bool f1();
    bool f2(int x);
    void f3(int y);
    struct Node tempNode;
public:
    A();
};


class B {
private:
    int v1;
    char c;
    long long v2;
    double v3;
    struct Node tempNode;
    bool f1();
    bool f2(int x);
    void f3(int y);
    
public:
    B();
};
```

**Class B** just has `struct Node tempNode` declaration moved from after functions declarations in **A** to all members declarations first then methods in **class B**.

**My doubt is, will **class B** more efficient than **class A** simply due to this reordering? or they will perform at the same level. Let me know even if the gains in **B** is very small.**

Comment: Member functions are not stored in the object, so have no effect on the storage layout.

Comment: Simplified : no there will be no difference, functions are not part of the memory allocated for an instance of a class. In fact when C++ calls a member function of a class it passes a pointer to the instance of the class as "hidden" first parameter to your functions. Side note :there is no need to put in "struct" before Node (that's a "C" anachronism).

Answer (score 3):

No, both classes will be laid out exactly the same in memory. Thus there's no performance difference.

Note that (non-virtual) member functions do not affect the layout of the data in memory. If you disregard them, you can easily see that both classes have the same layout.

Answer (score 1):

> will class B more efficient than class A simply due to this reordering?

No. Order of member functions in relation to data members or to each other has no effect on the program.

Comment: could you pls. explain what you meant by `Order if member functions in relation to has members or to each other has no effect on program.`?